# Voice over is not reading labels of inputs, just is content - safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, safari, voiceover

I'm using jquery and a similar example of this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/02urpsLg/1/

When forcing the navigation from Focus field to Focus in field, just is data is announced. This seems to happen due to $("#txtInput2").focus() (when removing that it works perfectly, but I really need to force the focus in a specific input).
Note: This happens with voice-over in safari.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

html:

```
<label id="ii" for="txtInput1">Focus</label>      <input id="txtInput1" type="text" aria-labeledby="ii" value="coisas"/><button>teste</button>

</button> <br /><br />
<label id="iii" for="txtInput2">Focus in</label>  <input aria-labeledby="iii" id="txtInput2" type="text" value="batatas"/> <br /><br />
<label id="iiii" for="txtInput3">Focus out</label> <input aria-labeledby="iiii" id="txtInput3" type="text" value="cebolas"/> <br /><br />
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#txtInput1").focus(
             function (event) {
                 $("#txtInput1").css("background-color", "Green");
             }
         );
         $("#txtInput1").focusout(
             function (event) {
                 $("#txtInput2").focus();
             }
         );
 
        $("#txtInput2").focusin(
             function (event) {
                 $("#txtInput2").css("background-color", "Yellow");
             }
         );
    
     $("#txtInput3").focusout(
             function (event) {
                 $("#txtInput3").css("background-color", "Red");
             }
         );
});
```

Comment: if you're facing similar issue, check this and let me know - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215298/safari-osx-voiceover-not-reading-aria-label-for-input

Comment: Hi Lakshman, Yes I'm facing a similar issue. I just don't have any blur event. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this issue? thanks